# Slim Framework PSR 4 with Controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, slim, psr-4

I am making an application based on Slim Framework. I am following PSR 4 pattern. This application is basically dealing with RESTful services. To make it more flexible for future we have adopted to use a different approach than conventional slim coding. 
My Directory structure looks like below,

```
│   autoload.php
│   composer.json
│   index.php
│   README.md
│
└───src
    └───Service
        ├───Component
        │   ├───Router
        │   │       Route.php
        │   │       RouterInterface.php
        │   │
        │   └───YamlLoader
        │           YamlLoader.php
        │           YamlLoaderInterface.php
        │
        ├───Core
        │       Bootstrap.php
        │       Settings.php
        │
        ├───Framework
        │   ├───Controller
        │   │       HomeController.php
        │   │
        │   ├───Model
        │   └───View
        └───Routing
                course.routing.yml
                home.routing.yml
```

In the "Routing" directory I will store some yaml files with the menu links. Those will be parsed in the Router Component to generate proper callable path to controllers and it's methods.

However, the problem I am facing is to determine which will be a good way to do so? How can I assign each router items from the .yml files and use them as

```
$app->map('/about', '\Service\Framework\Controller\HomeController:about')->via('GET', 'POST');
```

For further references, one of the yaml file looks like,

```
service.about:
  path: '/about'
  handler:
    _controller: '\Service\Framework\Controller\HomeController::about',
  http_method: GET

service.authenticate:
  path: '/auth'
  handler:
    _controller: 'Service\Framework\HomeController::auth',
  http_method: GET
```

What will be a good and efficient way? Please suggest.

Comment: How are you dinamically looping all the items in the yaml and what is your code in it?

Comment: I am using a foreach loop while parsing the yml file contents. However, I've found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, talked with a few in Slim IRC. And what I found is, any namespaced class should be supplied as a string. So,

```
\Service\Framework\Controller\HomeController
```

becomes

```
\\Service\\Framework\\Controller\\HomeController
```

And now it's working with,

```
$this->app->map('/hello', '\\Service\\Framework\\Controller\\HomeController:about')->via('GET');
$this->app->run();
```